# how do I convert to string in js

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that takes a string and uses the `ToLowerCase` Function and I want to be able to use the `charAt` function for example

```
  if (message.content.charAt(0) === '!'){
console.log('correct')
}
```

although that is a string and I have a variable named Text this is the Variable

```
var Text
  Text = message.content.toLowerCase()
```

although there is no error in this I want to be able to use the `charAt` function so I need it to be converted to a string how would I do this?

Comment: `String.prototype.toLowerCase()` returns a new string, what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toString()` method, something like this: `var text = message.content.toString().toLowerCase()`

Or also `var text = String(message.content).toLowerCase()`